# loop program terminated in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

This is my program which get terminated without running .In this i tried to print every hour, minute and second .

```
public class hello {
    String type;
    String name;
    static int hour = 0;
    static int min;
    static int sec;

    public static void  main(String args[]) {

        while(hour<12) {
            for(int mins = 0; mins <= 61; mins++) {
                min = mins;
                if(min==61) {
                    hour++;
                    min=0;
                    continue;
                }
                for(int secs = 0; secs>=61; secs++) {
                    sec=secs;
                    if(sec==61) {
                        min++;
                        sec=0;
                        continue;
                    }
                System.out.println("0"+hour+":"+min+":"+sec);
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

When i tried to print only minutes and hours by removing the second for loop and writing it this way it runs properly but when i add the code for printing seconds also it fails.

```
public class hello {
    String type;
    String name;
    static int hour =0;
    static int min;
    static int sec;

    public static void  main(String args[]) {
        while(hour<12) {
            for(int mins=0 ;mins<=61;mins++) {
                min = mins;
                if(min==61) {
                    hour++;
                    min=0;
                    continue;
                }
                System.out.println("0"+hour+":"+min+":"+sec);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: **please** edit your code and indent properly.  What do you think this for loop is doing?  "for(int secs = 0;secs>=61;secs++)"  Did you mean, using <= instead of >= ?  The loop will never be entered.

Answer (score 2):

The condition for seconds:

```
for(int secs = 0;secs>=61;secs++)
```

is flawed. Change the sign like this:

```
for(int secs = 0;secs<=61;secs++)
```

Comment: That loop still counts 61 seconds in a minute.

Comment: @KUSH42 This solves the problem: `the program doesn't terminate`. Other problems are different story and possibily different questions if the OP can't solve.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors in your logic:

1. First for-loop: Flawed testing expression because an hour only has 60 minutes, not 61
2. Second for-loop: Flawed testing expression: A minute only has 60 seconds, also you flipped the comparison operator
3. Modify if-checks accordingly

   ```
   public class Hello {

       static int hour = 0;
       static int min;
       static int sec;

       public static void main(final String args[]) {

           while (hour < 12) {
               for (int mins = 0; mins <= 60; mins++) {
                   min = mins;
                   if (min == 60) {
                       hour++;
                       min = 0;
                       continue;

                   }
                   for (int secs = 0; secs <= 60; secs++) {
                       sec = secs;
                       if (sec == 60) {
                           min++;
                           sec = 0;
                           continue;
                       }
                       System.out.println("0" + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec    );
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```